# AngularJS: compiled html alternates content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is a simple element directive that displays a name in bold:

```
WidgetsModule.directive('testwidget', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            name: '@'
        },
        template: '<p>My name is <b>{{name}}</b></p>',

        controller: function ($scope) {
            this.title = $scope.title;
        }
    };
})
```

This is a **partial page** of html that I load from the server:

```
<h1>My Partial Page</h1>
<testwidget name="Fred"></testwidget>
```

I have another directive called dymanicRefreshPanel, which has a div and a button.  When the button is pressed, the partial page is requested by an ajax post, and inserted into an element like this:

```
link: function (scope, element, attr) {

    scope.compileData = function (data) {

        var el = $compile(data)(scope);
        $(element).find("div.widget-body").html(el);

    }

}
```

When I first load the dynamic content, the browser shows this:

```
My name is Fred
```

The second time I request dynamic content, the browser shows this:

```
My name is {{name}}
```

The third time, back to the original:

```
My name is Fred
```

And then back and forth between the two.  The html that arrives by the ajax post is always the same.

What's going on?

Comment: Did you use `$http` to request the partial html? If not, did you call the `$scope.$apply()` after the `compileData()` has been called?

Comment: See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rIejsj1rz7HAx14bMSeA?p=preview), all seems to work fine.